# creating blank cordova app

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2015, hybrid-mobile-app, visual-studio-cordova, taco

I have created a blank cordova app, but the problem is that the project is empty, it only has dependencies. Can any one help me?

[image: look at the image here, please]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what Visual Studio Code did here, but you can always create and adapt a Hello World app by running `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld`.
Make sure you have [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm) installed, then run

```
npm install -g cordova
cd <your new project-folder>
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

Comment: thanks for answering, the hello world project created, but the problem is still remaining. when i build the project which i have created in visual studio i got this error message `The target "PreComputeCompileTypeScript" does not exist in the project` @geoM

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Visual Studio as code editor, not builder.

Building project is only need for compile apk for device (android).

```
cordova build android
```

No need to build simple project with index.html and JS files while developing. Just run:

```
cordova platform add browser
cordova run browser
```

PS: try Ionic-framework it's based on cordova.